Ex-convict builds playground funded with 5 gallon water drums full of coins
What is the name of the movie in which an ex-convict builds playground funded with 5 gallon water drums full of coins?  That's all I remember.

I believe you are referring to a 1990 movie called My Blue Heaven. Steve Martin plays a mobster named Vinnie who goes into witness protection but has trouble assimilating to civilian life. Rick Moranis is the FBI agent who is trying to keep Vinnie out of trouble.  Here is a YouTube clip from near the end of the film where the local DA is trying to have him arrested for "embezzling" the coins and how he really is building a park http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6n2l9BCoGNo 

This site rocks!
